# Retrieve rows where specific columns are different between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, gaps-and-islands

I have the following SQL to obtain both highest (max) and 2nd highest dated rows. There are some cases in the data where the only difference in the 'OLD ROW' and 'NEW ROW' is the effective date. What I would like to do is only show the old and new rows per EMPLID where either the BANK_CD and/or the ACCOUNT_NUM are different between the 'old' and 'new' rows.

```
   WITH CTE AS ( 
 SELECT A.EMPLID 
 , C.VENDOR_ID
 , B.FIRST_NAME 
 , B.LAST_NAME 
 , A.BANK_CD 
 , A.ACCOUNT_NUM 
 , A.ACCOUNT_TYPE 
 , A.PRIORITY
 , A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE 
 , A.EFFDT 
 , MAX(A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY A.EMPLID) AS MAX_UPDATE_DATE 
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.EMPLID 
  ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC 
  , D.EFFDT DESC) AS RN 
  FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT D INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A ON A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID 
   AND A.EFFDT = D.EFFDT INNER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES B ON B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID INNER JOIN PS_GHS_DIR_DEP_VND C ON C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID 
     INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB E ON E.EMPLID = A.EMPLID AND E.EFFDT = A.EFFDT AND E.PRIORITY = A.PRIORITY 
 WHERE B.EMPL_STATUS NOT IN ('T','R','D') 
   AND ((A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P' 
   AND A.AMOUNT_PCT = 100) 
    OR A.PRIORITY = 999 
    OR A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B') 
   AND D.EFF_STATUS = 'A' )

 SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'NEW ROW' WHEN RN = 2 THEN 'OLD ROW' END AS 
 'ROW_TYPE' , * 
 FROM CTE 
 WHERE RN IN (1, 2) 
 AND MAX_UPDATE_DATE >= GETDATE() - 8
```

Here is an example of output I am getting now:

```
ROW_TYPE    EMPLID     VENDOR_ID    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME    BANK_CD    ACCOUNT_NUM    ACCOUNT_TYPE    PRIORITY    LAST_UPDATE_DATE    EFFDT       MAX_UPDATE_DATE    RN
NEW ROW     12345      XYZ123       John          Smith        111111122  45678          C               999         03/12/2019          03/12/2019  03/12/2019         1
OLD ROW     12345      XYZ123       John          Smith        111111122  45678          C               999         10/25/2017          10/25/2017  10/25/2017         2
NEW ROW     47831      A86464       Samm          Bulle        754566654  98865          C               999         03/12/2019          06/08/2018  03/12/2019         1
OLD ROW     47831      A86464       Samm          Bulle        754566654  45678          C               999         10/25/2017          06/08/2018  10/25/2017         2
NEW ROW     32456      KG4561       Kilo          Renne        875123311  32146          C               300         09/02/2018          09/02/2018  09/02/2018         1
OLD ROW     32456      KG4561       Kilo          Renne        971215477  78131          C               310         12/21/2017          12/21/2017  12/21/2017         2
```

In the above example, I would NOT want to output the first two set of EMPLID rows (top 4 rows) as they have the same BANK_CD and ACCOUNT_NUM between the old and new row. The last set of rows I would want to keep in my output as you can see the BANK_CD and ACCOUNT_NUM are different (either could be though to be included).

I tried adding an self join for PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB and then adding in the WHERE clause where AND (A.BANK_CD <> E.BANK_CD OR A.ACCOUNT_NUM <> E.ACCOUNT_NUM) as follows:

```
   WITH CTE AS ( 
 SELECT A.EMPLID 
 --, C.VENDOR_ID
 , B.FIRST_NAME 
 , B.LAST_NAME 
 , A.BANK_CD 
 , A.ACCOUNT_NUM 
 , A.ACCOUNT_TYPE 
 , A.PRIORITY
 , A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE 
 , A.EFFDT 
 , MAX(A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY A.EMPLID) AS MAX_UPDATE_DATE 
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.EMPLID 
  ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC 
  , D.EFFDT DESC) AS RN 
  FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT D INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A ON A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID 
   AND A.EFFDT = D.EFFDT INNER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES B ON B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID INNER JOIN PS_GHS_DIR_DEP_VND C ON C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID 
 ---ADDING SELF JOIN BELOW---
     INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB E ON E.EMPLID = A.EMPLID AND E.EFFDT = 
     A.EFFDT AND E.PRIORITY = A.PRIORITY 
 WHERE B.EMPL_STATUS NOT IN ('T','R','D') 
   AND ((A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P' 
   AND A.AMOUNT_PCT = 100) 
    OR A.PRIORITY = 999 
    OR A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B') 
   AND D.EFF_STATUS = 'A' 
---ADDING NEW WHERE CONDITION BELOW---
   AND (E.ACCOUNT_NUM <> A.ACCOUNT_NUM OR E.BANK_CD <> A.BANK_CD )) 
 SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'NEW ROW' WHEN RN = 2 THEN 'OLD ROW' END AS 'ROW_TYPE' 
 , * 
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE RN IN (1, 2) 
  AND MAX_UPDATE_DATE >= GETDATE() - 8
```

When I make the above changes though, I do not get any data returned at all. What am I doing wrong?

**3/20/19 Edit:**

Following Tarek's suggested answer below, I seem to be missing some rows that I would expect to be in the final output. It appears that the new fields added `BANK_CD_prev` and `ACCOUNT_NUM_prev` are returning `NULL` values in the rows I am expecting them to be displayed, hence why the final query isnt retrieving them. How can this be dealt with?

```
ROW_TYPE    EMPLID    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME   BANK_CD       ACCOUNT_NUM     ACCOUNT_TYPE  PRIORITY    LAST_UPDATE_DATE       EFFDT        MAX_UPDATE_DATE  RN    BANK_CD_prev   ACCOUNT_NUM_prev  
NEW ROW     56789     Test          User        874556411     54765           C             999         2019-02-28             2019-02-28   2019-02-28       1     NULL           NULL
OLD ROW     56789     Test          User        874556411     98451           C             999         2017-10-09             2017-10-09   2017-10-09       1     874556411      54765
NEW ROW     56789     Sampl         Test        756561623     46331           C             999         2018-03-12             2018-03-12   2018-03-12       1     NULL           NULL
OLD ROW     56789     Test          User        756561623     46331           C             999         2015-05-18             2015-05-18   2015-05-18       1     756561623      46331
```

Please note the above is running the query **without** the final conditions for ( `AND BANK_CD <> BANK_CD_prev AND ACCOUNT_NUM <> ACCOUNT_NUM_prev` just so I could see why I was missing some rows. You can see in this case the first `EMPLID`'s two rows where the ACCOUNT_NUM is different and therefore I should be outputting both rows. The 2nd `EMPLID` (last two rows) is a little different in that the `BANK_CD` and `ACCOUNT_NUM` are the same for both rows, so I wouldn't expect this to be output (which it's not, so that is correct) but is still showing the `NULL`'s as in the first set of rows.

**3/20/19 Edit 2:**  You can see that the `BANK_CD_COUNT` and `ACCOUNT_NUM_COUNT` have some strange numbers in them that I think is causing a problem.

```
ROW_TYPE    EMPLID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   BANK_CD     ACCOUNT_NUM  ACCOUNT_TYPE   PRIORITY    LAST_UPDATE_DATE    EFFDT        MAX_UPDATE_DATE    RN   BANK_CD_COUNT  ACCOUNT_NUM_COUNT
NEW ROW     812682  Test        User        031308302   8675309      C              999         2019-03-09          2019-03-09   2019-03-09          1   1101            1
OLD ROW     812682  Test        User        231379393   0001236408   C           999            2018-04-11          2018-03-03   2019-03-09          2   476            1
```

This link contains Create Table and Insert scripts for anyone who could help replicate this.

https://pastebin.com/cZLhMmet

Comment: Hmmm...the output of the field *MAX_UPDATE_DATE* should repeat for each *EMPLID* being the max date by this ID. See demo: https://rextester.com/QEJB48817

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `LEAD` and `LAG` functions. We'll need both here.

Here is your original query, which I formatted and commented out the filter by date.

```
WITH 
CTE
AS 
(
    SELECT
        A.EMPLID
        ,C.VENDOR_ID
        ,B.FIRST_NAME
        ,B.LAST_NAME
        ,A.BANK_CD
        ,A.ACCOUNT_NUM
        ,A.ACCOUNT_TYPE
        ,A.PRIORITY
        ,A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
        ,A.EFFDT
        ,MAX(A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID) AS MAX_UPDATE_DATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC, D.EFFDT DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
        PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT D
        INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A 
            ON A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID
            AND A.EFFDT = D.EFFDT
        INNER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES B ON B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
        INNER JOIN PS_GHS_DIR_DEP_VND C ON C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
        INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB E 
            ON E.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
            AND E.EFFDT = A.EFFDT
            AND E.PRIORITY = A.PRIORITY
    WHERE 
        B.EMPL_STATUS NOT IN ('T','R','D')
        AND 
        (
            (
                A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P'
                AND A.AMOUNT_PCT = 100
            )
            OR A.PRIORITY = 999
            OR A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B'
        )
        AND D.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'NEW ROW'
        WHEN RN = 2 THEN 'OLD ROW'
    END AS 'ROW_TYPE'
    ,*
FROM CTE
WHERE 
    RN IN (1,2)
    --AND MAX_UPDATE_DATE >= GETDATE() - 8
;
```

This query returns the following result based on your sample data:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+
| ROW_TYPE | EMPLID  | VENDOR_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | BANK_CD  | ACCOUNT_NUM | ACCOUNT_TYPE | PRIORITY |    LAST_UPDATE_DATE     |          EFFDT          |     MAX_UPDATE_DATE     | RN |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+
| NEW ROW  |  097432 | 3471B     | H          | Adam      | 09146115 |    13404891 | C            |      999 | 2016-06-10 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-10 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-10 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| OLD ROW  |  097432 | 3471B     | H          | Adam      | 09146115 |    13404891 | C            |      999 | 2016-06-10 00:00:00.000 | 2014-11-05 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-10 00:00:00.000 |  2 |
| NEW ROW  |  100765 | 1272B     | V          | Milo      |  2358414 |      040925 | S            |      310 | 2014-03-05 00:00:00.000 | 2011-04-27 00:00:00.000 | 2014-03-05 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| OLD ROW  |  100765 | 1272B     | V          | Milo      |  2358414 |      040925 | S            |      300 | 2014-03-05 00:00:00.000 | 2001-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 2014-03-05 00:00:00.000 |  2 |
| NEW ROW  | 1045632 | 3870A     | V          | Olo       |  2345794 |   179410860 | C            |      999 | 2018-08-16 00:00:00.000 | 2018-08-16 00:00:00.000 | 2018-08-16 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| OLD ROW  | 1045632 | 3870A     | V          | Olo       |  2345794 |   179410860 | C            |      310 | 2011-02-25 00:00:00.000 | 2011-02-25 00:00:00.000 | 2018-08-16 00:00:00.000 |  2 |
| NEW ROW  |   21345 | 12345A    | J          | Smith     |  0224547 |    59167824 | C            |      999 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| OLD ROW  |   21345 | 12345A    | J          | Smith     |  0224547 |      591678 | C            |      999 | 2017-11-08 00:00:00.000 | 2017-10-17 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 |  2 |
| NEW ROW  |   26110 | 1272B     | S          | Sams      |  8208302 |      822328 | C            |      999 | 2019-02-08 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-08 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-08 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| OLD ROW  |   26110 | 1272B     | S          | Sams      |  8208302 |      822328 | C            |      315 | 2014-03-05 00:00:00.000 | 2012-07-30 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-08 00:00:00.000 |  2 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+
```

I included it here, so you can see the difference with the below.

Here is the new query with added `LEAD` and `LAG` functions (we need both to get the previous and next rows) with extra filter in the `WHERE` clause.

`LEAD` and `LAG` return NULL when they reach the end of the window. For example, `LAG` (prev value) would return NULL for the first row of the window, since there is no "previous" row yet.

So, for the first row (rn=1) we need to compare its value with the "next".

For the second row (rn=2) we need to compare its value with the "prev".

**Final query**

```
WITH 
CTE
AS 
(
    SELECT
        A.EMPLID
        ,C.VENDOR_ID
        ,B.FIRST_NAME
        ,B.LAST_NAME
        ,A.BANK_CD
        ,A.ACCOUNT_NUM
        ,A.ACCOUNT_TYPE
        ,A.PRIORITY
        ,A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
        ,A.EFFDT
        ,MAX(A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID) AS MAX_UPDATE_DATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC, D.EFFDT DESC) AS RN

        ,LAG(A.BANK_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC, D.EFFDT DESC) AS BANK_CD_prev
        ,LEAD(A.BANK_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC, D.EFFDT DESC) AS BANK_CD_next
        ,LAG(A.ACCOUNT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC, D.EFFDT DESC) AS ACCOUNT_NUM_prev
        ,LEAD(A.ACCOUNT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC, D.EFFDT DESC) AS ACCOUNT_NUM_next
    FROM 
        PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT D
        INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A 
            ON A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID
            AND A.EFFDT = D.EFFDT
        INNER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES B ON B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
        INNER JOIN PS_GHS_DIR_DEP_VND C ON C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
        INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB E 
            ON E.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
            AND E.EFFDT = A.EFFDT
            AND E.PRIORITY = A.PRIORITY
    WHERE 
        B.EMPL_STATUS NOT IN ('T','R','D')
        AND 
        (
            (
                A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P'
                AND A.AMOUNT_PCT = 100
            )
            OR A.PRIORITY = 999
            OR A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B'
        )
        AND D.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'NEW ROW'
        WHEN RN = 2 THEN 'OLD ROW'
    END AS 'ROW_TYPE'
    ,*
FROM CTE
WHERE 
    RN IN (1,2)
    AND 
    (
        (
            rn = 1
            AND BANK_CD <> BANK_CD_next
        )
        OR
        (
            rn = 1
            AND ACCOUNT_NUM <> ACCOUNT_NUM_next
        )

        OR

        (
            rn = 2
            AND BANK_CD <> BANK_CD_prev
        )
        OR
        (
            rn = 2
            AND ACCOUNT_NUM <> ACCOUNT_NUM_prev
        )
    )
    --AND MAX_UPDATE_DATE >= GETDATE() - 8
;
```

**Final result**

```
+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+--------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| ROW_TYPE | EMPLID | VENDOR_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | BANK_CD | ACCOUNT_NUM | ACCOUNT_TYPE | PRIORITY |    LAST_UPDATE_DATE     |          EFFDT          |     MAX_UPDATE_DATE     | RN | BANK_CD_prev | BANK_CD_next | ACCOUNT_NUM_prev | ACCOUNT_NUM_next |
+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+--------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| NEW ROW  |  21345 | 12345A    | J          | Smith     | 0224547 |    59167824 | C            |      999 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 |  1 | NULL         | 0224547      | NULL             | 591678           |
| OLD ROW  |  21345 | 12345A    | J          | Smith     | 0224547 |      591678 | C            |      999 | 2017-11-08 00:00:00.000 | 2017-10-17 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000 |  2 | 0224547      | NULL         | 59167824         | NULL             |
+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+--------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! One question, on the final result output I noticed the values for the `BANK_CD_next` and `ACCOUNT_NUM_next` for the 'NEW ROW' contain the 'OLD ROW's value for `ACCOUNT_NUM`.  And vice versa on the 'OLD ROW', the values for `ACCOUNT_NUM_prev` is the  `ACCOUNT_NUM` in the 'NEW ROW'. Maybe it's just the labeling of the field that is a little confusing (to me), I just wanted to make sure they are correct?

Comment: @Nick, everything is ordered according to `RN`. You labelled `rn=1`, the first row, as "NEW ROW". The row after `rn=1` is the row with `rn=2`. So, the next row for `rn=1` is the row with `rn=2`. The `ACCOUNT_NUM_next` column contains the value of the "next" row in the current row. So, for `rn=1` the column `ACCOUNT_NUM_next` contains the value from `rn=2`. And vice versa with "prev". When we bring values from two different rows into the same row we can compare them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, the partition on the lead and lag was in Descending (DESC) order so I think that's what caused my confusion. I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: good to hear, that your problem could be solved eventually, sorry for not responding as I've been on a conference.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add the following analytics functions to your CTE to return the predecessor:

```
LAG(A.BANK_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC) AS BANK_CD_prev,
LAG(A.ACCOUNT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLID ORDER BY A.EFFDT DESC) AS ACCOUNT_NUM_prev
```

Then you just need to reference that in your main query and you are done

```
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN IN (1, 2) 
AND MAX_UPDATE_DATE >= GETDATE() - 8
AND BANK_CD <> BANK_CD_prev
AND ACCOUNT_NUM <> ACCOUNT_NUM_prev
```

please reply, if that solved your problem. As you did not provide an example to test on it is hard to tell.

EDIT: I mean: use that solution with your initial approach without the self join at all. it will not help you on your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tarek for the feedback. I added in what you suggested, however I seem to be missing some rows with the extra conditions in the main query. The rows I am missing (that should be returned) are returning NULL values in the `BANK_CD_prev` and `ACCOUNT_NUM_prev` columns. I'll attach an example above.

Comment: Also when I run this with your changes I am only returning back the OLD ROW, whereas I want to see both the OLD ROW and NEW ROW.